# Div mouseover on a specific location on an image

Tags: css, image, html, mapping

I am currently building a fluid layout website, so that when the screen resolution changes, the site changes with it, no need for individual resolution css etc.

But the problem i am having is with the navigation bar, i want to have one image with the labels (Portfolio, Blog and About), when the mouse moves over each of those labels the whole nav bar changes to another navbar image, one with different coloration to indicate the mouse is on a specific label, each label needs to be a link too (obviously).

To try to clarify, i essentially need a div mouseover event on a specific location on an image, but as mouseover events don´t exist i would have to use :hover in css, but how do i get the image to change in css? Perhaps setting the original navigation bar image as the background image, but how do i overlay the next image and get it to activate on a specific hover location? image mapping?

regards, 
Jimy

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Comment: "As mouseover events don't exist"? I'm sorry, but I didn't get you. What about [JavaScript's mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseover) and [jQuery's mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)?

Comment: This sounds like a requirement for sprites...but until we see some code / images it's hard to comment further.

Comment: I said Div mouseover events, i was implying without the use of javascript or jquery. I will upload the code soon.

Comment: I can't upload images yet (need 10 points of rep first), but imagine a nav bar like the apple one, but made of one whole image, not individual elements.

Comment: I´ve searched for a solution to this but i haven´t found anything that fits. So i simply used a background image with label images ontop. Thanks for the help anyway guys.